# Set the time-of-day on a ZonedDateTime in java.time?

Tags: java, java-time, zoneddatetime

How can I alter the time-of-day portion of an existing [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object? I want to keep the date and time zone but alter the hour and minutes.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
zdt.with ( LocalTime.of ( 16 , 15 ) )
```

## Immutable objects

The java.time classes use the [Immutable Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern to create fresh objects rather than alter (“mutate”) the original object.

## `with()`

The [`ZonedDateTime::with`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) method is a flexible way to generate a new `ZonedDateTime` based on another but with some particular difference. You can pass any object implementing the [`TemporalAdjustor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface.

In this case we want to change just the time-of-day. A [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) object represents a time-of-day without any date and without any time zone. And `LocalTime` implements the [`TemporalAdjustor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface. So just that time-of-day value is applied while keeping the date and the time zone as-is.

```
ZonedDateTime marketOpens = ZonedDateTime.of ( LocalDate.of ( 2016 , 1 , 4 ) , LocalTime.of ( 9 , 30 ) , ZoneId.of ( "America/New_York" ) );
ZonedDateTime marketCloses = marketOpens.with ( LocalTime.of ( 16 , 0 ) );
```

Double-check that the duration of the span of time is as expected, six and a half hours.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between ( marketOpens , marketCloses );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "marketOpens: " + marketOpens + " | marketCloses: " + marketCloses + " | duration: " + duration );
```

> marketOpens: 2016-01-04T09:30-05:00[America/New_York] | marketCloses: 2016-01-04T16:00-05:00[America/New_York] | duration: PT6H30M

Keep in mind that in this example we are also **implicitly adjusting the seconds and fractional second** in the time-of-day. The `LocalTime` object carries with it the hour, minute, second, and fractional second. We specified an hour and a minute. Our omission of a second and fractional second resulted in a default value of `0` for both during construction of our `LocalTime`. All four aspects of the `LocalTime` were applied to get our fresh `ZonedDateTime`.

Quite a few classes implement the [`TemporalAdjustor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface. See the list on that class doc, including `LocalDate`, `Month`, `Year`, and more. So you can pass any of those to alter that aspect of a date-time value.

Read the comment by Hochschild. You must understand the behavior when you specify a time-of-day that is invalid for a specific date & zone. For example, during a Daylight Saving Time (DST) cut-over.

Comment: Correct examples. However, market opening and closing times are usually defined as local times, not as UTC-timestamps, so the types `LocalDateTime` and `LocalTime` are normally a better match (and also offer the `with()`-methods). But if you still insist on `ZonedDateTime` then don't be too surprised if the set time-of-day during a summer-winter-time-switch deviates from what you finally observe in the resulting object because JSR-310 can make an automatic adjustment (push-forward-strategy), admittingly a rare case and extremely unlikely for market times..